# CNN weights do not change in Keras with batch size 1

Tags: deep-learning, keras, backpropagation

I've a keras convolutional neural network model. When I execute:

```
def get_model_weights():
  model_weights = {}
  counter = 0
  for layer in model.layers: 
    weights = layer.get_weights()
    if (len(weights) != 0):
      counter += 1
      model_weights['W' + str(counter)] = weights
  return model_weights

x = np.zeros((1, 1, D, D))
x[0, 0, :, :] = cur_x #cur_x is a grayscale (1 channel) image (D x D pixels) 
y = np.zeros((1, 2))
y[0, :] = [1, 0]
init_weights = get_model_weights()
model.fit(x, y, batch_size = 1, nb_epoch = 1, verbose = 0)
cur_weights = get_model_weights()
```

**cur_weights** and **init_weights** are the same! It seems that weights are not updated! Can anyone explain this behaviour?! Is the "fit" implementation correct?!

Thanks

P.S. I'm using "stochastic gradient descent" as optimiser and "binary cross-entropy" as loss function

Comment: Can you provide your definition of `model`?

Comment: This problem can occur sometimes when using RELU activations in the model, for instance, because the gradient is flat (zero) in some places (causing the weights not to change). Try using a sigmoid activation and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: @MD004 Thanks for your answer. You're right. RELU might be the problem! I upgraded to Keras-2.0.8 and since then I don't see the problem.